# timelinechart couldn't decode Array as JSON:

Tags: polymer

I'm getting the issue "couldn't decode Array as JSON: " for the below chart. Rest of the charts seem to work with this format but not this one.

```
 <google-chart type='timeline' options='{"title": "Timeline", 
                                  "legend" : {"position" : "bottom", "alignment": "start"}
                                }' cols='[{"label":"Question", "type":"string"},
                                          {"label":"Number", "type":"string"},
                                          {"label":"Start", "type":"date"}, 
                                          {"label":"End", "type":"date"} ]'
rows='[["Question1", "1", new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0)],
      ["Question2", "2", new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,12,45,0)],
      ["Question3", "3",  new Date(0,0,0,12,45,0), new Date(0,0,0,1,0,0)],
      ["Question4", "4", new Date(0,0,0,1,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,1,12,0)],
      ["Question5", "5", new Date(0,0,0,1,12,0), new Date(0,0,0,1,30,0)]]'>
</google-chart>
```

Comment: Did you try passing in the dates in the `2018-04-12T09:03:20.863Z` format?

Comment: No but is that relared to the decode of json?

Comment: that didn't work. get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I little changed your code and its now working.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/GxaeMX)

```
<google-chart id="timeline" type='timeline' options='{"title": "Timeline"}'>

</google-chart>
```

and at the script:

```
ready() {
       super.ready();
       Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {this.showChartTable(); })
}

showChartTable(){

      var chart = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#timeline');
      document.createElement('google-chart-loader').dataTable([
          ['Question', 'Number', 'Start','End'],
        ["Question1", "1", new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1800, 3, 30)],      ["Question2", "2", new Date(1800, 3, 30), new Date(1900, 3, 30)], ["Question3", "3",  new Date(1900, 3, 30), new Date(2000, 3, 30)], ["Question4", "4", new Date(2000, 3, 30), new Date(2018, 3, 30)], ["Question5", "5", new Date(2018, 3, 30),new Date(2020, 3, 30)]] ).then(function(dataTable) {
          chart.data = dataTable;
        });
}
```

Due to timeline logic, you should define a valid time line. Your dates gives error.

EDIT: no need to keep this chart inside `connectedCallback`. just move on own named functions as: `showChartTable` (I changed)

Comment: when I use this this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#timeline') returns null

Comment: looks the the html hasn't loaded completly

Comment: Chek demo. Its working good. Don't forget to include `google-chart-loader` component.

Comment: Which polymer ver? Try= If > ver 2.0 ? This.$$.('#timeline')  ...you may read this:https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom

Comment: Mine is 2.0. I have loaded google-chart-loader. The issue seems to be that the google-chart element is not loaded by the time the connectedCallback is called. Why does this happen.

Comment: No problem, just move inside to an own named function and fire this function as you wish (with an observer or button or however). I will separate this. Or use it in ready function wrapped `Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {this.showChartTable(); })`

Comment: one issue seems to be that when I click on the timeline, the tooltip is coming in the bottom part and not as a popup. Same this is happening even in the demo that u have sent

Comment: Please follow this issue, this is a shadow Dom issue. I could not follow until the end. Hope you can find the solution from this link and let us know: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/issues/138